# Is it possible to hide Feature Points in ARKit?

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, arkit

I want to introduce in my app a toggle that will let the user to enable or disable the Feature Point.

The function that I'm talking about is:

```
self.sceneView.debugOptions = [ARSCNDebugOptions.showFeaturePoints]
```

Is it possible to disable it or it's in just one way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If feature points was the only debug option you turned on, you can easily turn it off (along with all other debug options) by setting debug options to the empty set:

```
self.sceneView.debugOptions = []
```

If you've set other debug options and want to remove *only* the feature points one, you'll need to take the current `debugOptions` value and apply some [`SetAlgebra`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/setalgebra) methods to remove the option you don't want. (Then set `debugOptions` to your modified set.)

Comment: Finally! Thank you very much! It was super easy but too many stuff to think about during an hard developing session...

Answer (score 0):

> **The answer is YES**,
>
> you can **enable** / **disable** `Feature Points` even if other `debugOptions` are `ON`. You can accomplish this by using `insert(_:)` and `remove(_:)` instance methods.

Here's a code (Xcode 10.2.1, Swift 5.0.1, ARKit 2.0):

```
let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
@IBOutlet weak var `switch`: UISwitch!
var debugOptions = SCNDebugOptions()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.delegate = self
    let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/model.scn")!
    
    debugOptions = [.showWorldOrigin]
    sceneView.debugOptions = debugOptions
    sceneView.scene = scene
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    sceneView.session.run(configuration)
}

@IBAction func featurePointsOnOff(_ sender: Any) {

    if `switch`.isOn == true {
        debugOptions.insert(.showFeaturePoints)
        sceneView.debugOptions = debugOptions
        print("'showFeaturePoints' option is \(debugOptions.contains(.showFeaturePoints))")

    } else if `switch`.isOn == false {
        debugOptions.remove(.showFeaturePoints)
        sceneView.debugOptions = debugOptions
        print("'showFeaturePoints' option is \(debugOptions.contains(.showFeaturePoints))")
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.